# Have metamask user pay minting fee, but owner sign transaction. onlyOwner and payable

Tags: solidity, truffle, nft, ethers.js, react

I want to allow a user to mint an NFT through my React app to a payable function, but I also want to control the URI and Token ID sent to the contract because we use many different folders on IPFS. Is this possible? If I have a payable function that is also onlyOwner, the owner's contract pays the minting fee, but I want the user to pay the minting fee. For example, in my React.js minting file

```
const mintBug = async (e, nextId) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);

      // If I use owner metamask private key owner has to pay
      // const { REACT_APP_METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;
      // const signer = new ethers.Wallet(
      //    REACT_APP_METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY,
      //    provider
      //  );

      // if I use this signer, the user pays
      const signer = provider?.getSigner();

      if (ContractAddress && signer) {
        const NFTContract = new ethers.Contract(
          ContractAddress,
          abi,
          signer
        );

        // payable amount from contract
        const value = await NFTContract.MINT_PRICE();

        const overrides = { value };

        // where userAddress is the address to send it to
        // and tokenURI is IPFS url
        await NFTContract.payableMintNFT(userAddress, nextId, tokenURI, overrides);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
     }
  };
```

And in the contract, for example

```
function mintNFT(address _toAddress, uint _tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) public payable onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(_toAddress, _tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);

        _numTokensMinted.increment();
    }
```

Is this even possible? Does anyone have any suggestions for other patterns to follow, like perhaps a payable function to reserve a token ID mapped to an address and then a separate minting function?

Comment: What do you mean by "I also want to control the URI and Token ID sent to the contract"

Comment: For our contract, the URL changes with every ~1000 NFTs or so generated. so we need to put in a different IPFS url whilst still keeping track of the id for each NFT